# Using PayPal Standard with Craft Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, payment-methods

Is it possible to use PayPal Standard with Craft Commerce? The docs are saying that Paypal is "fully supported", but I only see PayPal Express and PayPal Pro in gateways dropdown in conrol panel.

Answer (score 1):

Craft Commerce uses [Omnipay](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay) for its payment processing library.  Here's a list of the Omnipay officially supported 1st party gateways: https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay#payment-gateways

[Omnipay: Paypal](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-paypal) says it [supports](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-paypal#basic-usage) these Paypal services:

- PayPal_Express (PayPal Express Checkout)
- PayPal_ExpressInContext (PayPal Express In-Context Checkout)
- PayPal_Pro (PayPal Website Payments Pro)
- PayPal_Rest (Paypal Rest API)

Didn't have much Googling luck trying to find a 3rd party Omnipay plugins that support Paypal Standard, but there's always the option of writing an [Omnipay compatible one](http://omnipay.thephpleague.com/gateways/build-your-own/) that wraps the Paypal Standard API, then a [Craft plugin](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/payment-gateways#adding-additional-gateways) to bring that into Commerce.